# is there a simple way to check if given selector string point to only one element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

example

```
$('div.mydiv').checkifonlyone().css('background-color', 'red');
```

or maybe

```
$('div.mydiv').filter(':checkifonlyone').css('background-color', 'red');
```

I expect that there is only one div with that class in document, otherwise an error msg should be displayed and script should cease to execute ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could either look like:

```
$('div.mydiv:eq(0)').css('background-color', 'red');
```

That one would always select the first element if there are multiple.

or

```
var $mydiv = $('div.mydiv');
if($mydiv.length === 1) {
   $mydiv.css('background-color', 'red');
}
```

Which infact only would change the background color if there is exactly one match on the selector.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it yourself:

```
if ($(something).length !== 1)
    //Waaaah!
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var myDivs = $('div.mydiv');
if(myDivs.length === 1)
{
 myDivs.css('background-color', 'red');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( $('div.mydiv').length == 1 ) ....
```

Looking for that? Remember the jQuery element is an array of matches that are iterated by *most* of the functions (or a top element is popped off).

Answer (score 0):

You need [size() function](http://api.jquery.com/size/).

It will return numbers of elements in your selector and you can then act on that result accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your markup, you might be able to use the [`:only-child` selector](http://api.jquery.com/only-child-selector/), but you'll probably have to do something like this :

```
var $myDiv = $('div.mydiv');
if ($myDiv.length == 1) $myDiv.css('background-color', 'red');
```